# Finding the files related to confirmation email in checkout, opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using opencart version 2.1.0.1

I want to find the files related to confirmation email in opencart.

I don't know if the core files were changed but the confirmation email for orders, suddenly stopped working. Both the store owner and the customer don't receive them.

Can anyone give me the names of the files related to confirmation email, so that I can replace them with the original ones ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file at below location:

> your_project\catalog\model\checkout\order.php

The email code is at the last of the **confirm** function.

Comment: I hope this is the correct file. This files has no changes to the default file. Why isn't the confirmation email not being sent when an order is placed to both the store owner and the customer  ?

Comment: you should check you error log and see if there is any error being reported. Additionally you can check you mail settings by going to Admin->Settings->Edit->Mail. Also you can check if there is any mail being sent by going to "Admin->Sales->Email try and send an email and confirm.

Comment: Email is being sent on account signups, to both the customer and the admin. I can also send marketing e-mails. The problem is that only order email are not being sent. And the error log also doesn't say anything.